# Leyendo registro con PYMODBUS me da como resultado --> Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Tags: python, modbus

Cuando leo un Registro con el siguiente código :

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

adress = 43019-40001

response=client.read_holding_registers(address = adress ,count = 2,unit=1)
if response.isError():
    # handle error, log?
    print(response)
else:
    result = response.registers
    print(result)
```

Me da como resultado :

Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de [es.so], la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [ask]. Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Emilio, estás en [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Además, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: El address debería ser una resta de dos numeros o estar conformado por un numero, guion, otro numero?

Comment: Resta de dos numero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `read_holding_registers` añade el offset de 40000 automágicamente. Entrégale la dirección teniendo en cuenta esto.

Lo otro, por qué pones algo como una resta? Si lo estás fijando al codificar, por qué no simplemente pones la dirección?

El parámetro unit creo que va `unit=0x01`

Otra opción es que revises qué versión estás usando de pyModbusTCP, porque en la [versión más reciente](https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP), el método [está documentado](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/class_ModbusClient.html#pyModbusTCP.client.ModbusClient.read_holding_registers) con dos parámetros:

```
Parameters: 

    reg_addr (int) – register address (0 to 65535)
    reg_nb (int) – number of registers to read (1 to 125)
```

Comment: Hola que tal @Alfabravo te agradezco de antemano por tu tiempo, 
En esto del modbus para acceder al valor 0 deberia de empezar de esta manera 
address = 40001-40001 = 0 ; pero claro esta correcto lo que dices si le pongo directamente el valor; pero hay una tabla de valores que se guía desde el 40011 en adelante; entonces para entender mejor a que resultado estoy accediendo; hago la resta

Comment: En este caso quisiera entrar al resultado del address = 3018 ; es ahí donde me da el error de Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Comment: claro ya lo intente y me muestra el mismo error --> Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Comment: SI @Alfabravo, cambiando a response=client.read_holding_registers(address = 3001 ,count = 1,unit=0x01) aun sigo con el mismo error --> Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Comment: Por cierto @Alfabravo ; desde el 3001 hasta el 3155 me muestra esa excepción , si coloco como address = 2999  si obtengo un resulltado de = [65535]

Comment: @Emilio_ respuesta editada